# Why maven ran test even after a test failure?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

My understanding is maven would fail a build as soon as an assertion fails unless we specify the flag to run all tests.

However, it not clear why maven ran 2 tests even after 1 test has already failed.

Details: https://github.com/TQRG/BugSwarm/blob/6d65f8e080898f536dfd3669cad58aa57ed2fa23/docs/BugSwarm/square-retrofit-98261479/failing.log

```
Tests run: 101, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 0.337 sec
...
Failed tests:   callbackExecutorNullThrows(retrofit2.RetrofitTest): (..)
  converterNullThrows(retrofit2.RetrofitTest): (..)
```

Detailed log:

```
[0K$ mvn test -B
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.squareup.retrofit2:samples:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing. @ com.squareup.retrofit2:samples:[unknown-version], /home/travis/build/square/retrofit/samples/pom.xml, line 45, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Retrofit (Parent)
[INFO] Retrofit
[INFO] Adapters
[INFO] Adapter: RxJava
[INFO] Converters
[INFO] Converter: Gson
[INFO] Converter: Protocol Buffers
[INFO] Converter: Jackson
[INFO] Converter: Wire Protocol Buffers
[INFO] Converter: SimpleXML
[INFO] Converter: Java Scalars
[INFO] Converter: Moshi
[INFO] Retrofit Mock Adapter
[INFO] Samples
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Retrofit (Parent) 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- animal-sniffer-maven-plugin:1.14:check (default) @ parent ---
[INFO] Checking unresolved references to org.codehaus.mojo.signature:java16:1.1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Retrofit 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ retrofit ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ retrofit ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/travis/build/square/retrofit/retrofit/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ retrofit ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 44 source files to /home/travis/build/square/retrofit/retrofit/target/classes
[WARNING] /home/travis/build/square/retrofit/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Retrofit.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /home/travis/build/square/retrofit/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Retrofit.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ retrofit ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/travis/build/square/retrofit/retrofit/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ retrofit ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 8 source files to /home/travis/build/square/retrofit/retrofit/target/test-classes
[WARNING] /home/travis/build/square/retrofit/retrofit/src/test/java/retrofit2/RetrofitTest.java: /home/travis/build/square/retrofit/retrofit/src/test/java/retrofit2/RetrofitTest.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /home/travis/build/square/retrofit/retrofit/src/test/java/retrofit2/RetrofitTest.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ retrofit ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/travis/build/square/retrofit/retrofit/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running retrofit2.CallTest
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:00 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[41647] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:01 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
Running retrofit2.RequestBuilderTest
Tests run: 101, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 0.337 sec
Running retrofit2.ResponseTest
Tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running retrofit2.RequestFactoryParserTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec
Running retrofit2.RetrofitTest
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:02 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[55862] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:02 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[55862] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:02 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[50391] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:02 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[50391] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:02 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[33658] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:02 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[33658] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:02 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[54917] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:02 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[54917] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:02 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[42967] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:02 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[42967] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:02 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[37950] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:02 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[37950] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:02 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[37786] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:02 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[37786] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[34620] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[34620] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[43928] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[43928] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[44145] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[44145] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[59242] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[59242] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[47559] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[47559] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[60199] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[60199] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[42515] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$4 processOneRequest
INFO: MockWebServer[42515] received request: GET / HTTP/1.1 and responded: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[42515] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[34421] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[34421] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[39611] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[39611] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[38049] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[38049] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$4 processOneRequest
INFO: MockWebServer[38049] received request: GET / HTTP/1.1 and responded: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[50136] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[50136] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[41902] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[41902] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$4 processOneRequest
INFO: MockWebServer[41902] received request: POST / HTTP/1.1 and responded: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[60301] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[60301] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[47542] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[47542] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[38101] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[38101] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[49132] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[49132] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[39521] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[39521] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[39753] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[39753] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[45277] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[45277] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$4 processOneRequest
INFO: MockWebServer[45277] received request: GET / HTTP/1.1 and responded: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[41381] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[41381] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[33840] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[33840] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[53763] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[53763] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[60432] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[60432] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[39774] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[39774] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[52969] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[52969] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[34868] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[34868] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[51752] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[51752] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[52284] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[52284] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[34791] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[34791] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[51809] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[51809] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[40478] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[40478] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[58244] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[58244] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[45174] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[45174] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[51977] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[51977] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[48594] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[48594] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[51088] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[51088] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[57936] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[57936] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[32844] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[32844] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[60711] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[60711] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[36317] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[36317] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[41017] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[41017] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[42027] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[42027] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[46255] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[46255] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[48470] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[48470] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[48493] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[48493] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[42619] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[42619] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[50194] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[50194] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[46737] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[46737] done accepting connections: Socket closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[50922] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[50922] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[52413] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[52413] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[57896] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[57896] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[48679] starting to accept connections
Dec 22, 2015 6:09:03 AM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[48679] done accepting connections: Socket is closed
Tests run: 59, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.022 sec <<< FAILURE!
callbackExecutorNullThrows(retrofit2.RetrofitTest)  Time elapsed: 0.029 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting message:
 <"callbackExecutor == null">
but was:
 <"executor == null">
    at retrofit2.RetrofitTest.callbackExecutorNullThrows(RetrofitTest.java:1057)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$2.evaluate(MockWebServer.java:148)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

converterNullThrows(retrofit2.RetrofitTest)  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting message:
 <"converterFactory == null">
but was:
 <"factory == null">
    at retrofit2.RetrofitTest.converterNullThrows(RetrofitTest.java:744)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$2.evaluate(MockWebServer.java:148)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)


Results :

Failed tests:   callbackExecutorNullThrows(retrofit2.RetrofitTest): (..)
  converterNullThrows(retrofit2.RetrofitTest): (..)

Tests run: 207, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2
```

Comment: Tests can be run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding isn't correct. Maven will run all the tests in the module even if some of them failed. You can control this behaviour with parameter [surefire.skipAfterFailureCount](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skipAfterFailureCount). E.g.

```
mvn test -Dsurefire.skipAfterFailureCount=1
```